# date string doesn't show up in date input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have saved date as a string.

for example:
I have object in angularJs called myBirthday.

```
myBirthday.date="1996-04-04";
```

and I want to show the date in input in the modal:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myBirthday.date" />
```

The problem is that it's shown dd-mm-yyyy instead of 04-04-1996.
Then When I change the date,close modal and then reopen it,The input shows the correct date.

How can I make it to show the correct date? not dd-mm-yyyy?

I have tried almost every string types of date.
please HELP

Comment: I think it should be `$scope.myBirthday.date = ...` instead of just `myBirthday.date = ...`.

Comment: Are you using a datepicker also? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think it is date format error. Format your date before assigning it to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud create a Date object instead of a String.

```
myBirthday.date = new Date(1996, 3, 4);
```

You could also cast the Date to a String:

```
date_string = myBirthday.date.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems date filter called before binding of date or date-format values. date/dateformat is null initially but filter called that's why filter would be giving default format string. And once values are binded properly then everything works perfectly fine